# Sent event ignored

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling

I have a `QHeaderView`subclass inside a `QTreeView` subclass, the header provides information to the delegates which affects how they paint themselves.  The header receives mouse events that controls these values.

I also wanted my delegate editor widgets to provide the same functionality, but rather than copy and pasting the code that translates the mouse values into values the header could use, I thought it would be easier to re-send the `QMouseEvent` onto it.

So I copy the event and send it on (as noted in the [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent)):

```
QMouseEvent e( event->type(), event->pos(), event->button(),
               event->buttons(), event->modifiers() );
Sy_application::sendEvent( &header_, &e );
```

Only `header_` never receives it.  Posting the event has the same effect:

```
QMouseEvent* e = new QMouseEvent( QEvent::MouseButtonPress, event->pos(),
                                  event->button(), event->buttons(),
                                  event->modifiers() );
Sy_application::postEvent( &header_, e );
```

Why is `header_` not receiving the event?

Comment: This could perhaps be due to [event filtering](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) but that's just a guess...

Comment: I haven't installed any.  `sendEvent(....)` is returning true, which would imply that _something_ is handling it.  I'll take a look at the `QHeaderView` source code and see if there is one built in, the docs didn't mention one.

Comment: @tmpearce Nope, nothing in the `QHeaderView` or `QAbstractItemView::event(QEvent* e)` source code that looks like it cause this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my comment, about nothing in the parent classes causing this, must have been wrong.  As an experiment I overrode `event(QEvent* event)` in my header class to call the mouse handlers manually, and now it works perfectly:

```
bool Sy_timeLineHeader::event( QEvent* event )
{
    switch ( event->type() ) {
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        mousePressEvent( static_cast< QMouseEvent* >( event ) ); break;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        mouseReleaseEvent( static_cast< QMouseEvent* >( event ) ); break;
    case QEvent::MouseMove:
        mouseMoveEvent( static_cast< QMouseEvent* >( event ) ); break;
    default:
        return QHeaderView::event( event );
    }

    return true;
}
```

It hasn't affected the way the header operates normally, at least in so far as the way I am using it.